# Do US university professors consider papers published in IJERT

Tags: publications, graduate-admissions, professorship, research-undergraduate, online-publication

Do US university professors consider papers published in International Journal of Engineering Research and Technology (IJERT)?

For an undergraduate student applying for research program, what do professors check? The journal in which the research is published or the quality of the research, because I personally have had seen many papers getting desk rejected not because they are not up to the mark considering quality, but the editors had more better papers to publish.

Comment: This seems to be several question in one, and questions about specific journals are off-topic. For what it is worth, IJERT looks very suspicious to me just based on what they write about themselves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry but ...

It’s on the [blacklist of predatory journal](https://predatoryjournals.com/journals/#I) so yes it is considered, but considered very badly.  I would see this as a black mark against anyone, and in fact recommend you take it out of your CV if you are co-author.

The suggestion that a paper cannot be published because the “editors had more better paper to publish” is in itself a statement about the quality of the submission.